# Django: Change a DB record of a model extending an existing model by 1-1-relation

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am extending the default `User` model with a custom `Profile` model. They have a 1-to-1 relation (`OneToOneField`). The `Profile` stores custom settings of its user.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    allow_export = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language = models.CharField(max_length=8, default='en')
    theme = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='light')
```

I created a JS function which calls a Python API. The Python API should change the `theme` field of the **online** user (*the page can just be reached when the user is logged in.*).

So this is the API call. Please not that the function `request` is a simple post/get request. The only important thing I do here is to send a JSON object with `{theme: theme}`, for instance `{theme: 'dark'}`. The request works well.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

function changeTheme(theme) {
    let url = 'api/change-theme';
    let data = { theme: theme };
    let onSuccess = function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
    let onServerError = function () {
        console.log(data);
    }
    let onError = function () {
        console.log(data);
    }
    request('POST', url, data, onSuccess, onServerError, onError);
}
```

Now the issue: There is the python function `api_change_theme`. This function should change the `theme` of the user`s profile.

```
def api_change_theme(request):
    # Get post data
    post = json.loads(request.body)
    # Get theme name
    theme = post.get('theme', None)
    # Check if input is correct
    data = {}
    if theme is not None:
        # Save the new theme 
        u = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        u.profile.theme = theme
        u.save()
        data['success'] = True
        return JsonResponse(data)
    else:
        data['success'] = False
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

The important lines here are:

```
u = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
u.profile.theme = theme
u.save()
```

I want to get the user model which is currently online, then get its `profile` , change the `theme` of the users profile and store it.

But the code above does actually nothing. The python function returns `data['success'] = True` to my client, but the `theme` isn't changed.

So how can I change it?

Comment: Is there any reason for downvoting this question ??? I think it contains enough code examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're saving the user, not the profile.

Change

```
u.save()
```

to

```
u.profile.save()
```

and you're golden.

You can further optimize this with e.g.

```
Profile.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id).update(theme=theme)
```

to avoid fetching the full user, the full profile, then writing it all back.

(It should be noted that 1:1 Profile models are somewhat antiquated; we tend to use [custom user models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) these days.)

Comment: Just a further question about that: Are there disadvantages when using the default model with a extension class like I did? I already checked custom users but the main thing why I like the default user is that the registration,login, permissions ans groups are already integrated. I did these things x times and it is always the same. That's why I like the default model. Also I am going to implement data from a machine and therefore I need data tables with some 1:1 relations. Is this still in use or are there better alternatives? I am new to databases thats why I'am asking. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The registration, login, etc bits work just as well with custom users derived from BaseUser. The main disadvantage with extension classes is it's fiddlier (eg having to be sure the profile module exists for all users) and causes additional queries unless you're very careful with select_relateds everywhere.